# Blender Cycles - How to make particle planes to face towards the camera?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, camera

So I've been working on an explosion, with textured planes coming out of a particle system. Too bad it destroyes the whole feeling, when I can't see the texture on one of the planes, but a line, which is the plane, but not aligned to the camera. It also makes the middle of the explosion seen by the camera almost fully invisible, because there are no planes aligned to the camera. I tried to "Track To" the parent texture plane to the camera, but it only worked for that specific object, not the partices.

I couldn't find any solution not even on YouTube or Stackexchange so I'm asking you for help :)

Comment: This may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqBIAE8A-4k

Answer (score 1):

It seems to fix this issue, when I enable "Rotation" under the duplicate object selection in the Particle System settings.